# Default Timestamp Mysql

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Como coloco que o valor do campo tem por padrão `timestamp` atual?

Preciso `alterar` minha tabela para adicionar um campo `timestamp not null` que tem por padrão o atual, com isso preciso que todos os cadastros anteriores fiquem com a timestamp atual também.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao criar o campo, defina assim:

```
dataHora TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Caso vá modificar a estrutura de uma tabela já existente, convém usar uma *query* como esta **antes** da modificação, para não ter nenhum problema com `NULL`s já existentes (adaptada à sua necessidade, obviamente):

```
UPDATE minhaTabela SET dataHora = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE dataHora IS NULL;
```

Segue a *query* para modificar o campo:

```
ALTER TABLE
   minhaTabela
CHANGE
   dataHora
   dataHora TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

### Notas:

- Lembre-se que pode usar `DATETIME` também para armazenar datas que não mudam.
- Caso o campo esteja definido com `ON UPDATE`:

  ```
    dataHora TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ```

  seu campo será alterado nos `UPDATES` também. Caso não seja o efeito desejado, basta usar o `ALTER TABLE` acima sem definir o `ON UPDATE`.
- Para verificar a estrutura da tabela use:

  ```
    SHOW CREATE TABLE minhaTabela;
  ```

  pois o `EXPLAIN` não mostra definições `ON UPDATE`.

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu precisava. Obrigado.